# Import from pandas.io.json only works when running from python command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip, python-3.6

I am having an issue when trying to import:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```

when running a python program I have made. The same import works when running the code manually from the command line.

I am using Windows 10, with Python 3.6.5 installed.

**Example** - *working from command line:*

```
    >>> import pandas
    >>> from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
    >>> json_normalize
    <function json_normalize at 0x08319C90>
```

**Example** - *same code in test.py:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\Test\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.io'; 'pandas' is not a package
```

Any idea what I could check to see if I can resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure it's the same python in both cases?
Do you have more than one python installed?

Comment: Yeah I only have one Python installed, and it's also added to my PATH.